# Knockout validation: find out if a field is disabled by binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a field that's sometimes disabled, sometimes not

```
 <input type='text' class='input-small valid-number' id='height' data-bind='value: height, disable: (verticalAlignmentChosen() == "stretch"|| keepAspectRatio() == true)'>
```

The default value for it is 0. I want it so if it's disabled 0 is valid, if it's disabled it's not valid.

```
model.height.extend({
        validation: { validator: aboveZero, message: 'Can't be zero!' }
    });
```

Can I use an onlyIf option to do that? If yes, how?

Comment: You should probably add a `computed` property on your viewmodel which does the calculation you're currently doing in the binding. Then you could use that viewmodel property both for the `disable` bindina and the validation.

Comment: "I want it so if it's disabled 0 is valid, if it's disabled it's not valid."  Should one of those disableds be enabled?